# How to add custom headers in form_tag in rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using rails 4, and I need to implement password reset flow in devise_token_auth.

in controller

```
after_action :set_headers, only: [:reset_password]
def reset_password

end

def set_headers
   response.headers['uid'] = params[:uid]
   response.headers['client'] = params[:client_id]
   response.headers['access-token'] = params[:token]
end
```

reset_password.html.erb

```
  <h2>Change your password</h2>


 <%= form_tag('/api/v1/auth/password', :method=>'put') do %>
   <%= password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
   <%= password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>

   <%= submit_tag 'Change my password' %>

<% end %>
```

But headers are not going through. I tried printing the headers in passwords controller update method, but its printing nothing.
Please help how to add headers?
I have tried assigning headers in reset_password method also but it too didn't work.